# Replace (OCR) garbled text in PDF?

Tags: pdf, ocr

Now and then I come across a PDF which looks fine in first place but the underlying text is garbled. 
Currently I have a PDF where only the headings are garbled and I would like to know if it's possible to somehow replace the garbled text with the correct one.

I thought about OCRing the specific pages but this only works if I convert the page to an image.

How can I manually correct the underlying text or the re-OCR only specific parts?

Answer (score 0):

In  Acrobat Pro:
Veiw --> Tools --> Recognize Text

will bring up the OCR tool bar.  From there, use the "OCR Suspects" tools to correct the errors in the PDF.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work since this document hasn't been OCRed. There are no "OCR Suspects".
It's an "Vector-PDF" with copyable text. But the copied text of the headers is garbled.